# Changing background-color of fixed block at every new screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullpage.js

There is a page used fullPage.js with a fixed block, that must have to change their background-color every time, when i'm scrolling every new screen. Can't understand how can i make it. Any advices, please!

```
<div class="fixed"></div>
<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section"></div>
    <div class="section"></div>
    <div class="section"></div>
</div>
```

[example of page on codepen.io](https://codepen.io/vladikose/pen/MVqZbK)

Comment: please read docs https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/#fullpagejs

Comment: I don't think u understand my question correctly..

Comment: The fixed block "must have to change" their background-color? Can you please explain what do you mean by this.

Comment: ok, you have 3 slides, 100% width and height, and black fixed column on left side. You scroll one time, fixed column change background-color to pink, you scroll second time, it changes to blue etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the background color of that fixed div by using the `index` or `anchorLink` **[option in fullpage.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#options)**.

To change the css you can use `onLeave()` or `afterLoad()` method to call the function

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#fullpage').fullpage({
    onLeave: function(anchorLink, index) {
      //using index
      if (index == 1) {
        $(".fixed").css("background-color", "black");
      }
      if (index == 2) {
        $(".fixed").css("background-color", "blue");
      }
      if (index == 3) {
        $(".fixed").css("background-color", "red");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.fixed {
  width: 25%;
  height: calc(100vh - 50px);
  background-color: #000;
  margin: 25px;
  float: left;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
}

.section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: pink;
}

.section:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: green;
}

.section:last-of-type {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.9.6/jquery.fullpage.min.js"></script>
<div class="fixed"></div>
<div id="fullpage">
  <div class="section"></div>
  <div class="section"></div>
  <div class="section"></div>
</div>
```

**[Updated Codepen](https://codepen.io/bhuwanb9/pen/OvoqPj)**